# Why does this consumer (running on a servlet) not receive any messages from the kafka topic?

Tags: java, servlets, apache-kafka, consumer

I've setted up an kafka-consumer on my servlet. I read from my kafka topic and want to print the latest value using the doGet-method of the servlet.

But if I send the doGet I just get a "null" back...

I'm not sure, but I found another post, where somebody mentioned, that this might be because there is no connection to the zookeeper servers. So I tried to fix this adding the `zookeeper.connection` to the properties of the consumer; even if it's outdated.

Hopefully someone could give me advice about this.

> Code of my Servlet:

```
public class KafkaServlet extends HttpServlet implements Runnable {

public String kafkaMessage;
private Properties props;
private KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer;
Thread Trans;

/**
*   setting up the properties and other consumer using the constructor of KafkaServlet
*/
public KafkaServlet() {
    props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092"); //replace 'localhost' with the actual IP to get it working.
    props.put("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
    consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("kafkaTopic"));
}

/**
*   setup the thread and run it using the init-method
*/
@Override
public void init (ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    Trans = new Thread(this);
    Trans.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
    Trans.start();
}

/**
*   implement the doPost-Method if we want to use it 
*/
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //empty -- nothing to post here
}

/**
*   doGet will get print out our returned message from kafka
*/
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

res.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
String title = "Reading Parameters from kafkaTopic";

out.println("<HTML>" +
            "<BODY>\n" +
            "<H1 ALIGN=CENTER>" + title + "</H1>\n" +
            "<UL>\n" +
            "  <LI>MESSAGE: "
            + kafkaMessage + "\n" +
            "</UL>\n" +
            "</BODY></HTML>");
}

/**
*   thread, which grabs the messages from kafka and stores the latest one in "kafkaMessage"
*/
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                //KafkaMessage.setMessage(record.value());
                kafkaMessage = record.value();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        consumer.close();
    }
}}
```

> EDIT: Latest logfiles from "localhost.log":

`19-Dec-2016 13:42:42.773 INFO [localhost-startStop-2]  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener:  contextDestroyed()
 19-Dec-2016 13:42:42.774 INFO [localhost-startStop-2]  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener:  contextDestroyed()
 19-Dec-2016 13:42:54.742 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener:  contextInitialized()
 19-Dec-2016 13:42:54.745 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener:  contextInitialized()`

Comment: It looks like you are trying to build an HTTP Proxy. You might want to look at the code for the existing REST Proxy from Confluent. https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest

Comment: Thanks, I had a look into the sourcecode, but there were no significant differences for the config and setting up the consumer.

But I figured the problem out, by replacing the "localhost" on the "bootstrap.servers" with my actual IP of my VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: the problem, why I did not receive any messages was the line `props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");`.

I had to change the "localhost" to my actual IP of my VM. This is kinda strange, because every other property I configured (on apache storm; kafka; another servlet which contains an kafka producer) was working well with "localhost".

Comment: It's recommended that Kafka brokers run on standalone hardware or VMs so you probably want to run your Proxy on a separate machine when you get to production.